# Loop all objects within a table mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a table with 4,1 million objects and now want to loop over all objects do something with them creat an additional key + value to the schema and replace the original object within the database.

How can i loop over the all objects using mongodb. I'm looking for a solution with minimun ram and cpu usage

Comment: did you try using streams?

Comment: im just starting with node... will streams be the solution to handle the huge amount of data? something like find(.*) will crash the application...

Comment: stream will fetch results in batch (like 1 or 100 at a time) instead of overwhelming memory with all the documents.